# iOS simulator suddenly stopped working, 'iOS simulator was unable to boot', no other message

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, osx-elcapitan

When I click run in Xcode, that is the message that pops up, but it worked a few days ago... I tried resetting the simulator settings but that did nothing. I have read that iOS simulator doesn't work on El Capitain, but that doesn't explain why it worked a few days ago and then randomly stopped working.

Comment: A more detailed error message should appear in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log ... what does it say?

Comment: I don't see that file or folder. If I go /Library/Logs the only folder in /Logs is /DiagnosticReports and a there's a file called LKDC-setup.log.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place.  Look in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator.  NOT /Library/Logs/...

Comment: There is no CoreSimulator folder though.

Comment: If you've ever run simctl or launched Simulator.app, the folder certainly is there.  You are missing the ~ in your comment above.  Look in your home directory for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, the ANSWER is UPDATE. People said this but I didn't have any available updates, but after a few days an update showed up in the appstore and after updating OSX, the simulator ran fine.